# Typing for an array of certain values, where each value may appear at most once? (TypeScript)

Tags: arrays, typescript, subset

Say I have a function like the following:

```
function getUserInfo(desiredProperties: ('name' | 'age' | 'salary')[]) {
  const userInfo: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  for (const propertyName of desiredProperties) {
    userInfo[propertyName] = fetchEffortfullyFromDatabase(...);
  }
  return userInfo;
}
```

Now if I call the function "normally", say

```
const userInfo = getUserInfo(['name', 'salary']);
```

everything is fine.
But nothing prevents one from a call like

```
const userInfo = getUserInfo(['name', 'name', 'name', ...]);
```

triggering many unnecessary database accesses. Of course, this could simply be handled within `getUserInfo` at runtime, but I want the compiler to recognize and forbid such calls.

I could change `('name' | 'age' | 'salary')[]` to the union of all possible combinations of the propertyNames, i.e. `['name'] | ['name', 'age'] | ['name', 'age', 'salary'] | ['age'] | ...`, but this is too tedious even for three values and hardly doable for more (especially when taking the order into account).

So, is there another way to get the desired typing? Maybe something like `AllCombinations<'name', 'age', 'salary'>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Set` type capability to extract only unique members of passed argument:

```
function getUserInfo(desiredProperties: ('name' | 'age' | 'salary')[]) {
  const uniqueMembers = new Set(desiredProperties); // this extract only unique members of array
  const userInfo: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  for (const propertyName of uniqueMembers) { // and here you iterate only through unique members
    userInfo[propertyName] = fetchEffortfullyFromDatabase(...);
  }
  return userInfo;
}

let userInfo = getUserInfo(['name', 'salary']);

userInfo = getUserInfo(['name', 'name', 'name']);
```

Of course, such a solution is not perfect, because it assumes runtime unnecessary computations.

If you don't want to have unnecessary computations, you can set the type of `desiredProperties` as `Set<'name' | 'age' | 'salary'>`. And then call to `getUserInfo` like this:

```
const userInfo = getUserInfo(new Set(['name', 'salary']));
```